# How to serve Ratchet WS connection on vps?

Tags: php, websocket, vps

I had vps and already uploaded my site files, but I cant connect to the ws server ,

My server file code

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new chat_server()
        )
    ),
    8080 
);
```

and in js file

```
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://myDomain.com:8080");
```

but when opening the site an error of

> ws.js:51 WebSocket connection to 'wss://myDomain.com:8080/' failed:

what is wrong or should be done ?

Comment: You are asking SSL version of the server (wss) but your server created insecurely. So you have to call ws://mydomain.com:8080